# Angular/TypeScript – sort array of strings which includes numbers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting

I have an array like:

```
arr = ["100 abc", "ad", "5 star", "orange"];
```

I want to sort firstly strings with no numbers at the beginning and then strings with numbers add at the end, omit numbers and sort strings by name alphabetically.

Expected output:

```
ad, orange, 100 abc, 5 star.
```

How can I do that in TypeScript/Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```js
const startsWithNum = (str) => /^\d/.test(str);

const afterNumPart = (str) => str.match(/^\d+\s(.*)/)[1];

const compareStrings = (a, b) => {
  if (startsWithNum(a)) {
    if (startsWithNum(b)) {
      // Both strings contain numbers, compare using parts after numbers
      return afterNumPart (a) < afterNumPart (b) ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
      // A contains numbers, but B does not, B comes first
      return 1;
    }
  } else if (startsWithNum(b)) {
    // A does not contain numbers, but B does, A comes first
    return -1;
  } else {
    // Neither string contains numbers, compare full strings
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
  }
};

const arr = ["100 abc", "ad", "5 star", "orange"];
const sortedArr = arr.sort(compareStrings);
// ['ad', 'orange', '100 abc', '5 star']
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, it almost works but after adding two similar items to the arr:   
`arr = ["100 abc", "ad", "5 star", "orange", '100 def', '5 ad'];`

It seems to not work as expected because result is:

`ad,orange,100 abc,100 def,5 ad,5 star`

While expected is:

`ad,orange,100 abc,5 ad,100 def,5 star.`

Do you maybe know, how to handle that?

Comment: I have adjusted the issue description to clarify the missing point.

Comment: Ah, I had an error. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The question is actually about partitioning rather than sorting. You can achieve this easily with two `filter` calls:

```
result = [
    ...arr.filter(a => !/\d/.test(a)),
    ...arr.filter(a =>  /\d/.test(a)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
const arr = ["100 abc", "ad", "5 star", "orange"]
arr.map(item => {
        return item.split(' ').map((subItem: string) => +subItem ? +subItem : subItem)}
        ).sort((a,b) => {
            if(a.find((item: any) => typeof item === 'number')){
                return 1;
            }else return -1
    }).map(item => item.join(' '))
```

Comment: This puts all the non-numbered items before the numbered items, but I don't think it sorts them alphabetically.

Comment: You can add this logic inside the sort() method

Comment: Thank you! The same here, it almost works but after adding two similar items to the arr: `arr = ["100 abc", "ad", "5 star", "orange", '100 def', '5 ad'];` It seems to not work as expected because result is: `ad,orange,100 abc,100 def,5 ad,5 star` While expected is: `ad,orange,100 abc,5 ad,100 def,5 star`. I have adjusted the issue description to clarify the missing point.

Comment: I see. As I said before, all you have to do is to mnipulate the sort() method logic. You can sort it according to any condition you like, but the structure stays the same.